# How to call constructor inside the class?

Tags: c#

I want to call constructor inside the class  like:
    public class Myclass(){

```
   public MyClass(){
      //......
   }

   public MyClass(int id):this(){
      //......
   }

   private void Reset(){
      //.....
      this = new MyClass(id);    //here I want to call constructor
      //......
   }
}
```

but it is not working. Is it possible and how can I do it if Yes?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You can't alter the `this` pointer that way inside an instance method, nor should you want to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. But what you could do is split the constructor logic into an Initialize method that then reset could call.

```
   public MyClass(){
   //......
   }

   public MyClass(int id):this(){
      Initialize(id);
   }

   private void Initialize(int id){
   //....
   }

   private void Reset(){
      //.....
      Initialize(id);
      //......
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Simple answer: You can't.

Slightly more complicated answer: Move your initialization logic into a separate method that can be called from the constructor and your `Reset()` method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? Id { get; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClass(int id)
    {
        Initialize(id);
    }

    public Reset()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private Initialize(int? id = null)
    {
        // initialize values here instead of the constructor
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly succinct and clear and helped my own understanding immensely.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. You cannot assign to this.

You could however let `Reset()` return a new instance of `MyClass` so the caller code could say:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass Reset()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c = c.Reset();
```

Or you could implement the `Reset` method in such a way that all fields are reinitialized to their default values.

Comment: I like the idea of Reset() returning a new instance, in that case should probably be `static` though.

Comment: If a new instance was returned, it's no longer Resetting anything. It's returning a freshly created instance of the class. Kind of misleading.

Comment: True, perhaps `Create()` would be a better method name.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - Unless you're creating an object factory, you should really just use new...which makes this suggestion a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* call a constructor for your class inside your class (in fact this is often done with factory methods):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();   
    }
}
```

But you can't change the value of the `this` reference inside the class.  You should instead have your "Reset()" method set the fields back to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

Within a class you can't reassign `this` (although it's worth noting that within a struct it's perfectly legal). The question, though, is whether you *should*. I assume that your goal is to set all field values to a specific state, so as other people have already said you can either have your Reset method return a new instance or you can break out your logic into a Clear() method and call that instead.