# Call derived class constructor before base class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, constructor, overriding

I need to execute derived class constructor before base class constructor.
I am attaching code which is using virtual object in base class which need to be initialised in derived class. We decide type of virtual object in derived class and then assign values to that object once we have type of that object.
How could I call derived class constructor before base class constructor in this scenario.

```
public class BaseClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Path ConnIn;
    public Path ConnOut;

    public virtual ObjectBase BaseObject { get; set; }

    public void BaseClass(XmlElementConfig config)
    {
        this.BaseObject.Title = config.Title;
        this.BaseObject.GroupID = config.GroupID;
    }
}

public partial class DerivedClass : CanvasBase
{
    private Audio_MonitorAction audio_objectAction;

    public override ObjectBase BaseObject
    {
        get { return audio_objectAction; }
        set
        {
            audio_objectAction = (Audio_MonitorAction)value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DerivedClass(XmlElementConfig config) : base(config)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        audio_objectAction = new Audio_MonitorAction(createGuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call constructor inside the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730192/how-to-call-constructor-inside-the-class)

Comment: I am having the same problem.  How are you supposed to use virtual methods in a base constructor, why was this crap error implemented anyways.  You don't need to call the base constructor first in C++, why do you need to do it a very loosely coupled language like javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"execute derived class constructor before base class constructor" is impossible

if possible, move initialization into `BaseObject` property (why should it be virtual?)

```
public class BaseClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Path ConnIn;
    public Path ConnOut;

    private ObjectBase baseObject;
    public ObjectBase BaseObject
    {
        get { return baseObject; }
        set
        {
            baseObject = value;
            if (baseObject != null)
            {
                baseObject.Title = config.Title;
                baseObject.GroupID = config.GroupID;
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    XmlElementConfig config;
    public void BaseClass(XmlElementConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

```
public partial class DerivedClass : CanvasBase
{
    private Audio_MonitorAction audio_objectAction;

    public DerivedClass(XmlElementConfig config) : base(config)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BaseObject = audio_objectAction = new Audio_MonitorAction(createGuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have written is simplest and optimised way to achieve inheritance with single base and derived class. But I have derived more than 20 different classes from base class, the solution you written need to be written more than 20 times. What i asked is to call base constructor after derived constructor. Also you give negative marking to my question which is not the way if you don't have the proper solution. Also you removed the concept of virtual and override form my class which is necessity. I want the code which can be written in single statement and no need to call separately.

Comment: short answer: "execute derived class constructor before base class constructor" **is impossible**.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Path ConnIn;
    public Path ConnOut;

    public virtual ObjectBase BaseObject { get; set; }

    public void BaseClass(XmlElementConfig config)
    {
        InitBase(config);
    }
    protected void InitBase(XmlElementConfig config)
    {
        if (BaseObject != null)
        {
            BaseObject.Title = config.Title;
            BaseObject.GroupID = config.GroupID;
        }
    }
}
public DerivedClass(XmlElementConfig config) : base(config)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    audio_objectAction = new Audio_MonitorAction(createGuid);
    InitBase(config);
}
```

**Alternatively** you can do in BaseClass call to virtual function and override it in derived class.

```
public class BaseClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Path ConnIn;
    public Path ConnOut;

    public virtual ObjectBase BaseObject { get; set; }

    public void BaseClass(XmlElementConfig config)
    {
        InitDerivedClass();
        if (BaseObject != null)
        {
            BaseObject.Title = config.Title;
            BaseObject.GroupID = config.GroupID;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void InitDerivedClass() {}
}
public partial class DerivedClass : CanvasBase
{
    private Audio_MonitorAction audio_objectAction;

    public override ObjectBase BaseObject
    {
        get { return audio_objectAction; }
        set
        {
            audio_objectAction = (Audio_MonitorAction)value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    protected override ObjectBase InitDerivedClass
    {
        audio_objectAction = new Audio_MonitorAction(createGuid);
    }
    public DerivedClass(XmlElementConfig config) : base(config)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rekshinno The code you have written is simplest and optimised way to achieve inheritance with single base and derived class. But I have derived more than 20 different classes from base class, the solution you written need to be written more than 20 times. What i asked is to call base constructor after derived constructor. Also you give negative marking to my question which is not the way if you don't have the proper solution. I want the code which can be written in single statement and no need to call separately.

Comment: @Praveensharma First - I havn't down voted you. Second - see comment from ASh. You can't call a base constructor in a method, extract it to the method, or put it to the base setter as ASh suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution. It works for me and the code now seems to be in  simplest form and could be called from one centre location only.